# Correct SQLServer statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

We are creating a VB program for school to collect data on student attendance and populate it to a table. I have all of the 'GET' statements but am having trouble creating the 'Insert' procedure. This is what I have so far. The form being used to fill the table has 4 items being recorded. 'Present' radio button marked as present, tardy or absent; StudentId, PeriodId and date. Not sure if we are on the right track. The target table is tmAttendance. There are approximately 25 rows of data on the input form.

Thanks in advance!

```
INSERT INTO tmAttendance
VALUES (Present, StudentId, PeriodId, Date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for T-SQL syntax, your statement is correct, but it will be more readable if you define the fileds of the tmAttendance:

```
INSERT INTO tmAttendance(field1, field2, filed3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...)
```

I have not understand from your question what is the type of "Present" field. You need to be sure that value you insert into table has the same type with field of the table.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO tmAttendance VALUES ([Present], StudentId, PeriodId, [Date])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tmAttendance
([Present], [StudentId], [PeriodId], [Date]) 
VALUES 
('TARDY', '123', '1', '2012-03-27')
```